# Multilayered Tikz picture with containders, nodes, arrows, boxes and png images

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drafting an architecture for my thesis (see the attachment) using tikz and struggling a lot. Tikz architecture needs to have .png images incorporated. Find the code below to see some development.

I am also attaching all the .png images that needs to be incorporated in the architecture. Please help me in drafting it.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
            calc,
            fit,
            positioning,
            shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
rrbox/.style={%rounded red box,
rectangle,
draw, rounded corners, thick, fill=red!20,
minimum height=8mm, minimum width=24mm,
text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
align=center
        },
sum/.style={% summation
circle,
draw=black, minimum size=8mm,
append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
    \draw[thick,shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, -]
        (\LN.north) edge (\LN.south)
        (\LN.west)   to  (\LN.east);
%        \draw[blue] (\LN.center)  circle (1.414*4 mm);
            }},% end of nappend after command
    node contents={}
        },
disk/.style={% cylinder
cylinder, shape border rotate=90,
draw, fill=red!20,
aspect=0.25,
minimum height=12mm, minimum width=54mm,
align=center
        },
container/.style={
rectangle,
draw, rounded corners,
inner sep=4mm, yshift=2mm,
node contents={}
            },
line/.style={
draw, thick, dashed, -latex',
        },
    }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=8mm and 4mm,
                    ]
% Container 1, on the left side
\node (sum) [sum]; % sumation
\node (a11) [rrbox, above left=4mm and 18mm of sum.west] {some text a11};
\node (a12) [rrbox, left =of a11] {some text a12};
\node (a21) [rrbox, below=of a11] {some text a21};
\node (a22) [rrbox, below=of a12] {some text a22};
\draw[line] (a12) edge (a11)
        (a12) edge (a22)
        (a11) edge (a21)
        (a22)  to  (a21);
\node (container1) [container, fit=(a11) (a22),
                label={[anchor=north]Some more Text}];
% Container 2, on the right side
\node (b11) [rrbox, above right=4mm and 18mm of sum.east] {some text b11};
\node (b12) [rrbox, right =of b11] {some text b12};
\node (b21) [rrbox, below=of $(b11.south)!0.5!(b12.south)$] {some text b21};
\draw[line] (b12) edge (b11)
        (b11) edge (b21)
        (b12)  to  (b21);
\node (container2) [container, fit=(b11) (b12) (b21),
                label={[anchor=north]Some more Text}];
% Container 3, on the upper side
\node (c11) [rrbox, above=of sum] {some text c11};
\node (c12) [rrbox, above=of c11] {some text c12};
\draw[line] (c12)  to  (c11);
\node (container3) [container, fit=(c11) (c12),
                label={[anchor=north]text}];
% cylinder
\node (d) [disk, below=of sum |- container1.south] {some text here\\in two 
lines};
% Lines to and from the summation
\draw[line] (container1.east |- sum) edge (sum)
        (container2.west |- sum) edge (sum)
        (container3) edge (sum)
        (sum) to ($(d.before top)!0.5!(d.after top)$);
%
\node(container4) [container, yshift=-2mm,
   fit=(container1)(container2)(container3) (d)];

\node (e1) [rrbox, minimum width=50mm, below=of d] {Some Text \\ in e1};
\node (e2) [rrbox, minimum width=50mm, left=of e1] {Some Text \\ in e2};
\node (e3) [rrbox, minimum width=50mm, right=of e1] {Some Text \\ in e3};
\node (container5) [container,yshift=-1mm, below=of container4, fit=(e1) (e2) 
(e3)];       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you can add arbitrary graphics with `\node at (...) {\includegraphics{<graphic.png>};` ? These nodes can be used to fit in boxes like all other nodes.

Comment: Also, if you give Ti*k*Z contradictory directions, it does not always produce nice output. For instance, in the very last node in which you fit others, `yshift=-1mm, below=of container4,` just makes the nodes not fit. In order to increase the distance to the nodes above, you need to move the fitted nodes down.

Comment: Sorry, am about to go hibernating now.

Comment: No problem. I ll be waiting for your reply. I ll update the question if there will be any further development.

Comment: you actually ask for service "do-this-instead-me". you should be more specific, where you stuck in coding of image, otherwise this is to broad question and probably be closed as to broad. in answer below i add (to my solution on your previous question)  some part of your desired image, which show a way, how you can write code further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only part of desired image, however it contain all elements that you can finish yourself:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
            calc,
            fit,
            positioning,
            shapes.geometric,
            shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{
rbox/.style={% red box,
rectangle,
draw, rounded corners, thick, fill=red!20,
minimum height=8mm, minimum width=24mm,
text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
align=center
        },
ibox/.style={% image box,
rbox, draw=none, fill=#1
        },
sum/.style={% summation
circle,
draw=black, minimum size=8mm,
append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
    \draw[thick,shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, -]
        (\LN.north) edge (\LN.south)
        (\LN.west)   to  (\LN.east);
            }},% end of nappend after command
    node contents={}
        },
disk/.style={% cylinder
cylinder, shape border rotate=90,
draw, fill=red!20,
aspect=0.25,
minimum height=12mm, minimum width=54mm,
align=center
        },
container/.style={
rectangle,
draw, rounded corners,
inner sep=4mm, yshift=2mm,
node contents={}
            },
line/.style={
draw, thick, dashed, -latex',
        },
    }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=8mm and 4mm,
                    ]
% Container 1, on the left side
\node (sum) [sum]; % sumation
\node (a11) [rbox, above left=4mm and 18mm of sum.west] {some text a11};
\node (a12) [rbox, left =of a11] {some text a12};
\node (a21) [rbox, below=of a11] {some text a21};
\node (a22) [rbox, below=of a12] {some text a22};
\draw[line] (a12) edge (a11)
        (a12) edge (a22)
        (a11) edge (a21)
        (a22)  to  (a21);
\node (container1) [container, fit=(a11) (a22),
                    label={[anchor=north]Some more Text}];
% Container 2, on the right side
\node (b11) [rbox, above right=4mm and 18mm of sum.east] {some text b11};
\node (b12) [rbox, right =of b11] {some text b12};
\node (b21) [rbox, below=of $(b11.south)!0.5!(b12.south)$] {some text b21};
\draw[line] (b12) edge (b11)
        (b11) edge (b21)
        (b12)  to  (b21);
\node (container2) [container, fit=(b11) (b12) (b21),
                    label={[anchor=north]Some more Text}];
% Container 3, on the upper side
\node (c11) [rbox, above=of sum] {some text c11};
\node (c12) [rbox, above=of c11] {some text c12};
\draw[line] (c12)  to  (c11);
\node (container3) [container, fit=(c11) (c12),
                    label={[anchor=north]text}];
% cylinder
\node (d) [disk, below=of sum |- container1.south] {some text here\\(in two
lines)};
% Lines to and from the summation
\draw[line] (container1.east |- sum) edge (sum)
            (container2.west |- sum) edge (sum)
            (container3) edge (sum)
            (sum) to ($(d.before top)!0.5!(d.after top)$);
%
\node(container4) [container, yshift=-2mm,
   fit=(container1)(container2)(container3) (d),
   label={[anchor=north east] 30:part 2}];
% part 3
\node (e2) [rbox, minimum width=50mm, below=16mm of d] {Some Text \\ in e1};
\node (e1) [rbox, minimum width=50mm, left =of e2] {Some Text \\ in e2};
\node (e3) [rbox, minimum width=50mm, right=of e2] {Some Text \\ in e3};

\node (i1) [ibox=white, below right=4mm and 0mm of e1.south west]
    {some text\\xxxx xxxxx\\yy yy yy};
\node (i2) [ibox=red!20, right=of i1]
    {\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-duck}};
\node (i3) [ibox=white, below  left=4mm and 0mm of e3.south east]
    {some text\\xxxx xxxxx\\yy yy yy};
\node (i4) [ibox=red!20, left=of i3]
    {\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-duck}};
\node (container5) [container, fit=(e1) (i3),
    label={[anchor=north east] 12:part 3}];
\draw[very thick, ->] (container4) -- (container5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```